# asp email arabic configuration with iis7

Tags: html, asp.net, iis-7

I have an HTML form which added to IIS and I am using asp.net in order to send email; in latin characters I have no issues; however, when passing arabic letters I receive in my inbox question marks. Here are the codes in asp

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"

'EmailSubject = request.querystring("subject")
EmailBody = request.querystring("name") & " " & request.querystring("email") & vbcrlf & request.querystring("message")
Const EmailFrom = "sender@gmail.com"
'Const EmailFromName = request.querystring("fullname")
Const EmailTo = "recepient@gmail.com"
Const SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
Const SMTPLogon = "user@gmail.com"
Const SMTPPassword = "password"
Const SMTPSSL = True
Const SMTPPort = 465

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1    'Send message using local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2  'Send the message using SMTP over TCP/IP networking.

Const cdoAnonymous = 0  ' No authentication
Const cdoBasic = 1  ' BASIC clear text authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2   ' NTLM, Microsoft proprietary authentication

' First, create the message

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = EmailSubject
objMessage.From = """" & EmailFromName & """ <" & EmailFrom & ">"
objMessage.To = EmailTo
objMessage.HtmlBody = EmailBody

' Second, configure the server

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = SMTPLogon

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = SMTPPassword

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SMTPPort

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = SMTPSSL

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
'Now send the message!
On Error Resume Next
objMessage.Send
%>
```

I tried many charset with no luck (such as Windows-1256, ISO-8859-6)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found a solution I deleted the lines below

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

and added under `Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")`the code:

```
objMessage.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```